# Can't load assets

Tags: functions, css

I finished some project and this script for loading assets worked fine. But now in another project something is weird. I can't load .js and .css

```
<?php
function add_css_js() {
  wp_enqueue_script('main-javascript', get_theme_file_uri('/js/main.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
  wp_enqueue_style( 'tailwind', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_css_js');
```

This is how looks my folder: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G37lS.png

Comment: Can you show us the `<link>` and `<script>` tags that these generate, and tell us what the correct paths for each should be and what's different? Is one project a theme and the other a child theme?

Comment: @Rup that's weird, because it's not generated. Look this https://i.imgur.com/T4pdB4D.png

I don't know how this Loom font generated ...

Comment: OK: are you missing the [`wp_head()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/) and [`wp_footer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/) calls from your theme's header and footer templates? That's where the <link> and <script> tags that you've enqueued get generated. (You're also missing a <title> from the <head> block, but that won't be the issue here.)

Comment: @Rup 
no, I added that already

header.php
https://i.imgur.com/mXO4cPI.png


footer.php
https://i.imgur.com/CfHJzXQ.png

Comment: The screenshot you sent with the font-face definitions doesn't have the HTML language tags or the two meta tags that you've got in header.php. Are you definitely using header.php then? (But if you are then I'm out of ideas.) What's generating the font-face style block?

Comment: I was confused, multiple projects reason :D ...

Inside index.php I didn't called   get_header();

Create new .php file and added that, works fine